# Web Service client in Python using ZSI - "Classless struct didn't get dictionary"

Tags: python, wsdl, zsi

I am trying to write a sample client in Python using ZSI for a simple Web Service. The Web Service WSDL is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="test" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">
  <wsdl:message name="NewOperationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="NewOperationRequest" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="NewOperationResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="NewOperationResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="test">
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:NewOperationRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:NewOperationResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="testSOAP" type="tns:test">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/test/NewOperation"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body namespace="http://www.example.org/test/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body namespace="http://www.example.org/test/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="test">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:testSOAP" name="testSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/test"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Every time I run following code:

```
from ZSI.ServiceProxy import ServiceProxy
service = ServiceProxy('test.wsdl')
service.NewOperation('test')
```

I receive:

```
(...)
/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/ZSI/TCcompound.pyc in cb(self, elt, sw, pyobj, name, **kw)
    345             f = lambda attr: pyobj.get(attr)                                        
    346             if TypeCode.typechecks and type(d) != types.DictType:                   
--> 347                 raise TypeError("Classless struct didn't get dictionary")           
    348                                                                                     
    349         indx, lenofwhat = 0, len(self.ofwhat)                                       

TypeError: Classless struct didn't get dictionary
```

I have searched Google for this error and I found couple posts describing similar problem but with no answer. Do you know was is wrong here? Is there an error in the WSDL, do I miss something in the code or there is a bug in ZSI?

Thank you in advance for you help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution.

I should run like this:

```
from ZSI.ServiceProxy import ServiceProxy
service = ServiceProxy('test.wsdl')
service.NewOperation(NewOperationRequest='test')
```

The reason of the problem was that the name of the parameter was missing (sic!) - silly error ;-)